# Template contains errors.: Template format error: At least one Resources member must be defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am pretty new to this CloudFormation thing and while creating a Stack in S3 service I am getting this error in Creating a template in Designer option.

`Template contains errors.: Template format error: At least one Resources member must be defined.`

This is my template.yaml file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  HelloBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
Outputs:
  HelloBucketDomain:
    Description: Domain of the Bucket
    Value: !GetAtt HelloBucket.DomainName
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Template you pasted here looks okay, would double check that's the template being deployed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to add it in the components window of the designer mode you will get the above error.

Rather, select template in designer mode and copy paste your code (left bottom) and opt for JSON or YAML (In your case its YAML)

[image]

In the component mode after you paste the code and hit refresh you wont see the component added in the designer, even though you have code in the component tab its not reflecting the designer window and hence you are getting the error.

So use template instead of component.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It works!! actually I was on the components tab instead of template one.

Comment: Cool, If this was helpful, you can mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Just take a look at [What is voting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)